# LSTM parity generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I am trying to learn deep learning, I have stumbled on one exercise [here](https://blog.openai.com/requests-for-research-2/)

It is first warm-up exercise. I am stuck. For constant sequence of small lengths(2,3) it solves it no problem. However when I try whole sequence of 50. it stops at 50% accuracy, which is basically random guess.

According to [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/j-LBOuorJyw) it is too big flat space ant cant find gradient to solve it. So i tried approach of continuously increasing length ans saving model each time (2,5,10,15,20,30,40,50).It seems it does not generalise well, as if i type bigger sequence then what I learned it on, it fails.

According to [here](http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2016/10/21/1d-grid-lstm-and-the-xor-problem.html) it should be easy problem. I cant figure it out. There is used some different LSTM architecture hoverer.

And one solution [here](https://bobsaget4lyfe.github.io/post/2018-02-02-xor-deep-learning/) to exactly same problem says it works with Adagrad optimizer and learning rate of 0.5.

I am unsure about one bit at time, if I am feeding it right in first place. I hope I got it right.

And for variable length, i tried and failed miserably.

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adagrad, Adadelta
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import time
import os.path

# building the model
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(
        32,
        input_shape=(None, 1),
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(
        1))
    model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

    return model

# generating random data
def generate_data(num_points, seq_length):
    #seq_rand = np.random.randint(1,12)
    x = np.random.randint(2, size=(num_points, seq_length, 1))
    y = x.sum(axis=1) % 2

    return x, y

X, y = generate_data(100000, 50)
X_test, y_test = generate_data(1000, 50)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=0,
                          write_graph=True, write_images=False)

if os.path.isfile('model.h5'):
    model = load_model('model.h5')
else:
    model = build_model()

opti = Adagrad(lr=0.5)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opti, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
model.fit(
    X, y,
    batch_size=10, callbacks=[tensorboard],
    epochs=5)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                       batch_size=1,
                       verbose=1)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Model saved')
model.save('model.h5')
```

I am so confused now. Thanks for any response!

Edit: Fixed return_sequences to False typo from previous experiments.

Comment: Are you sure your code is working? Shouldn't be there `return_sequences=False`?

Comment: You are right, i had two LSTM layers, removed second and forgot to rewrite return_sequences. Now it runs fine. Question stands still.

Comment: Does your loss saturate around `0.69`?

Comment: It does saturate around 0.69 if i choose loss='binary_crossentropy'. When i use loss='mse' as shown here, it saturates at 0.25. Which i assume is saying same thing in different way.

Comment: Yes - it simply constantly predicts `0` - as you may easily check :)

Comment: Either all 0 or 1. Nearly all of them. Predict hovers around 0.5, and then it is rounded to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might be a really valuable exercise about `LSTM` and vanishing gradient. So let's dive into it. I'd start from changing task a little bit. Let's change our dataset to:

```
def generate_data(num_points, seq_length):
    #seq_rand = np.random.randint(1,12)
    x = np.random.randint(2, size=(num_points, seq_length, 1))
    y = x.cumsum(axis=1) % 2
    return x, y
```

and model by setting `return_sequences=True`, changing the loss to `binary_crossentropy` and `epochs=10`. So well - if we solve this task perfectly - then we'd also solve the initial task. Well - in 10 out of 10 runs of the setup I provided I observed the following behavior - for first few epochs model saturated around 50% of accuracy - and then suddenly dropped to 99% of accuracy.

**Why have this happened?**

Well - in `LSTM` a sweet spot for parameters is a synchrony between memory cells dynamics and normal activation dynamics. Very often one should wait a lot of time in order to get such behavior. Moreover - the architecture needs to be sufficient in order to catch valuable dependencies. In a changed behavior - we are providing much more insights to a network thanks to which it could be trained faster. Still - it takes some time to find the sweet spot.

**Why your network failed?**

Vanishing gradient problem and problem complexity - it's completely not obvious what information network should extract if it gets only a single signal at the end of the sequence of computations. This is why it needs either supervision in the form which I provided (`cumsum`) or a lot of time and luck in order to finally find a sweet stop on its own.

Comment: Thanks! when i change from sum to cumsum, it solves the problem, because it sees the whole process of generating instead of result only.Now I struggle with variable lengths to get working, because it accepts as input only tensor. How is it possible to achieve it? One approach is batch_size and call fit in iteration, but this is horribly slow. Another approach is masking, but how? I cannot mask with 0 because it carries information.

Comment: I solved even variable sequence with Masking layer and 2 as mask - it does not change result of parity. It learns no problem and then is able to take arbitrary sequence length. It seem it learned well, since it is able to predict correctly sequence of 1000. More I did not test. Thanks for hint!